# Updating scikit-learn: 'SVC' object has no attribute '_probA'?

Tags: python, scikit-learn

We updated to Python 3.8.2 and are getting an error with scikit-learn:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "manage.py", line 16, in <module>
execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
File "/home/ubuntu/myWebApp/.venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 381, in execute_from_command_line
utility.execute()
File "/home/ubuntu/myWebApp/.venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 375, in execute
self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
File "/home/ubuntu/myWebApp/.venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 316, in run_from_argv
self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
File "/home/ubuntu/myWebApp/.venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 353, in execute
output = self.handle(*args, **options)
File "/home/ubuntu/myWebApp/server_modules/rss_ml_score/management/commands/rssmlscore.py", line 22, in handle
run.build_and_predict(days=options['days'], rescore=options['rescore'])
File "/home/ubuntu/myWebApp/server_modules/rss_ml_score/utils/run.py", line 96, in build_and_predict
predict_all(filename)
File "/home/ubuntu/myWebApp/server_modules/rss_ml_score/models/predict_model.py", line 135, in predict_all
voting_predicted_hard, voting_predicted_soft = predict_from_multiple_estimator(fitted_estimators, X_predict_list,
File "/home/ubuntu/myWebApp/server_modules/rss_ml_score/models/train_model.py", line 66, in predict_from_multiple_estimator
pred_prob1 = np.asarray([clf.predict_proba(X)
File "/home/ubuntu/myWebApp/server_modules/rss_ml_score/models/train_model.py", line 66, in <listcomp>
pred_prob1 = np.asarray([clf.predict_proba(X)
File "/home/ubuntu/myWebApp/.venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sklearn/svm/_base.py", line 662, in _predict_proba
if self.probA_.size == 0 or self.probB_.size == 0:
File "/home/ubuntu/myWebApp/.venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sklearn/svm/_base.py", line 759, in probA_
return self._probA
AttributeError: 'SVC' object has no attribute '_probA'
```

Do I need to use another library in addition to sci-kit learn to access _probA?

**Update** in response to a comment:

The line of code that's throwing the error is:

```
pred_prob1 = np.asarray([clf.predict_proba(X)
                         for clf, X in zip(estimators, X_list)])
```

...that calls this line in `_base.py`:

```
def _predict_proba(self, X):
    X = self._validate_for_predict(X)
    if self.probA_.size == 0 or self.probB_.size == 0:
```

...which calls this line, also in `_base.py`:

```
@property
def probA_(self):
    return self._probA
```

...which throws the error:

> AttributeError: 'SVC' object has no attribute '_probA'

All this has worked fine for many months, but is not currently working, even after updating to the latest `scikit-learn.`

Comment: Are you returning `probA_` and internally it's returning `_probA`? Just wondering because it should be `probA_`

Comment: @Chrispresso, I've updated the post with additional info responsive to your question.

Comment: Please show the code for fitting your `SVC` classifier.

Comment: @VikR did you create the SVC with `probability=True`? I believe it's only available if you first create the SVC object with parameter `probability` set to `True`.

Comment: @Chrispresso it is, that's why I asked

Comment: I was informed that if I update to the latest package, the old training models won't work anymore, so I have to **not** upgrade.

Answer (score 9):

It turned out that I had to stay with the same version of sci-kit that was used to train the models we currently have (scikit-learn==0.21.2). Later versions of scikit don't work with our existing code / models.  If we want to upgrade scikit, we have to retrain our models with the new version of scikit.

Answer (score 3):

A little late, but I have just stumbled across a very similar problem and managed to solve it by adding the code below before deserializing (unpkling) the model:

```py
from typing import Any, Dict

from sklearn.svm import OneClassSVM


original_oneclass_setstate = OneClassSVM.__setstate__

def __monkey_patch_oneclass_setstate__(self, state: Dict[str, Any]) -> None:
    """
    Monkey-patch the `setstate` method of the `OneClassSVM` to rename
    attributes that changed only the name from version `0.22`.
    """
    if "proba_" in state:
        state["_probA"] = state.pop("probA_")
    if "probB_" in state:
        state["_probB"] = state.pop("probB_")
    original_oneclass_setstate(self, state)

OneClassSVM.__setstate__ = __monkey_patch_oneclass_setstate__


# Deserialize the model here
```

My case was nearly the same as yours, to update models trained on `scikit-learn==0.22` (not `0.21.2`) for running on newer `scikit-learn~=1.0.2`, and they run with success.

On version `0.22`, the model contained `probA_` and `probB_` internal attributes, but no properties `_probA` or `_probB` (as show in your case). They renamed these attributes on newer versions to `_probA` and `_probB` (as attributes, not properties). Inspecting the model before the fix, what I found was just two empty numpy arrays:

```py
'probA_': array([], dtype=float64),
'probB_': array([], dtype=float64),
```

So, another approach you could try is to just set these attributes to empty numpy arrays and compare if they generate the same prediction values than with the older `0.21.2` version.

Answer (score 0):

I also had this error and I tried so much to resolve it. At the end it got resolved by just version compatible issues. Whatever the version used in building the model, the same version should be used in load